# Diagonal elements of a mutual information matrix

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

Mutual information is a metric from information theory that quantifies the non-linear co-dependencies between a pair of random variables. When extended to more than one pair, a mutual information matrix can be constructed, similar to the correlation matrix.

Clearly the off-diagonal elements are pair-wise estimates of mutual information, but what are the diagonal elements in a mutual information matrix? are they the individual variables' absolute entropy?

Comment: I have never heard of such a matrix before. So its $(x,y)$ entry is the mutual information of the marginal probability of the quantities $x$ and $y$? Then yes, the mutual information of the probability of a quantity with itself is its Shannon entropy. At least if you consider $x' \equiv x$ as a "copy" of itself, so that $\mathrm{p}(x,x') = \mathrm{p}(x)\ \delta(x,x')$.

Comment: I guess the OP is referring to multiple comparisons. In that case, the diagonal elements represent the MI between the random variable and itself, which is the entropy of the random variable.

Comment: Are the diagonal elements, each being the MI between a random variable and itself, **Shannon entropy** in the discrete case *as well as* **differential entropy** in the continuous case? Someone says self-MI is Shannon entropy, but this doesn't hold for differential entropy, but I don't see why not?